# Normal Approximation to Poisson problem

Tags: probability

Suppose we have code with $ = 100$ pages. The variable $$ is the number of errors on the page that is distributed Poisson meets the average of 1. Also, the number of errors per page is independent of the other page. Number The total errors are calculated as $ = Σi $. Using the central limit theorem Estimate $( <90)$.

Since this is a normal Approximation to Poisson problem. i should use the $Z=Y−λ/√λ⟶N(0,1)$ therefore, $P(Y<90) = P(Z<\frac{90-1}{1})$?

And how can i get the P(Z<89) from z table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key fact to use here is that the sum of independent Poisson RVs also has a Poisson distribution with a rate that is the sum of the individual rates. Specifically, since $X_i \sim Pois(1)$, $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{100} X_i \sim Pois(100)$. Since $Y$ is Poisson with parameter 100, both it's mean and variance are 100. You can approximate $Y$ with a normal random variable $Z \sim N(100, 100)$.

Now, to estimate the probability of interest, $\mathbb{P}(Y < 90) \approx \mathbb{P}(Z < 90) = \mathbb{P}(Z_{norm} < (90-100)/10) = \mathbb{P}(Z_{norm} < -1)$, where $Z_{norm}$ is a standardized normal RV with mean 0 and variance 1. You can look this up from standard tables to get the answer 0.1587.